# Say i have $n$ points in the plane all of which are connected. What is the minimum number of intersections between the connecting lines?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, computational-geometry, combinatorial-geometry

Say i have $n$ points in the plane all of which are connected with segment lines. What is the minimum number of intersections between the connecting lines?
Note 1: We count the number of intersections not intersection points, so even if three lines intersect in 1 point that's 3 intersections.
Note 2: There can not be 3 points in a line.
Here is the case for n=5 with one intersection.

[image]

Comment: Are the lines infinite, or just segments?

Comment: @Bernard Segments.

Comment: Can be three points in a line?

Comment: @mfl no three points in a line

Comment: See https://oeis.org/A000241 and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossing_number_(graph_theory)#Complete_graphs_and_graph_coloring and http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GuysConjecture.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to find the [crossing number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossing_number_(graph_theory)#Complete_graphs_and_graph_coloring) of the complete graph $K_n$. As you'll see in the link, the best upper bound on the crossing number is
$$
\frac{1}{4} \left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor \left\lfloor \frac{n-1}{2} \right\rfloor \left\lfloor \frac{n-2}{2} \right\rfloor \left\lfloor \frac{n-3}{2} \right\rfloor. 
$$
It is known that the crossing number equals this upper bound for $n=5, 6, \ldots, 12$ and it is conjectured to hold for all $n \geq 5$.

Comment: That seems to be exactly what I was looking for. Is the upper bound rigorously proven though?

Comment: Yes, the upper bound part has been proved